# Create multiples objects with different parameters

Tags: java, oop

I have trouble to making "levels" in my FROGGER game in java. What i try to do is create different levels but I'm looking for a way to do it dynamically without having to add all the elements manually.

For all items, parameters are X and Y positions. (except Driveway)

For Driveway :

- the first parameter is the direction of the driveway AND when i create a group of driveways in a row, they have to be in the same direction.
- the second parameter is the Y position
- the third is the "groupe" of the driveway (basicaly what i describe above such as "driveways in a row that have the same direction".

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks for your help !

```
    private void generateMapOfLevels() {

    switch (this.level) {
        case 1 -> {

            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(0, 60));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 30, 5));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(0, 90));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 120, 4));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 150, 4));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(0, 180));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(0, 210));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 240, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 270, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(0, 300));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 330, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 360, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 390, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 420, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 450));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 480, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 510, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 540, 1));
            generate("log");
            generate("coin");
            generate("insect");

            fixedGameElementList.add(new Pill(getRandomCoordinate(), getRandomCoordinate()));

        }


        case 2 -> {
            resetLists();
            resetVariables();
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 60));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 30, 5));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 90));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 120, 4));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 150, 4));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 180));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(0, 210));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 240, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 270, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 300, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 330));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 360));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 390, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 420, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 450));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 480, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 510, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 540, 1));
            generate("log");
            generate("coin");
            generate("insect");
            fixedGameElementList.add(new Pill(getRandomCoordinate(), getRandomCoordinate()));

        }

        case 3 -> {
            resetLists();
            resetVariables();

            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 30, 5));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 60, 5));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 90));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 120, 4));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 150, 4));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(1, 180));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 210, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 240, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 270, 3));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 300));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new River(1, 330));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(1, 360));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(1, 390, 2));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new CentralBerm(1, 420));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 450, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 480, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 510, 1));
            fixedGameElementList.add(new DriveWay(-1, 540, 1));
            generate("log");
            generate("coin");
            generate("insect");
            fixedGameElementList.add(new Pill(getRandomCoordinate(), getRandomCoordinate()));
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to create array of elements, generate number of total elements, in loop get random element for each with random parameters.

You can get random numbers in range you need using this function

```
public int getRandomNumberUsingInts(int min, int max) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.ints(min, max)
      .findFirst()
      .getAsInt();
}
```